# Understanding the working of "IsNull" function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

**Access Code**

```
iif(Format(SUM(Field))='',0,SUM(Field))
```

**SQL code**

```
IsNull(SUM(Field),0) As Amt
```

In the **Access Code statement** it is clearly shown that the query has to run **SUM function** 2 times to get **SUM** and **0** if records are blank.

But I want to know that **internally how many times SQL is running SUM function in the SQL statement**? 1 or 2? Please provide some explanation.

Comment: Once (as [opposed to `COALESCE`](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) btw, search "Used with Subqueries").

Comment: MySQL **or** MS SQL **or** both ? Normally, if you have `null` values, you'd use it like: `SUM(IFNULL(field, 0))` - because it doesn't automatically cast `null` to `0` (-MySQL).

Comment: sorry question only SQL

Comment: It's tagged `sql-server` and no mention of `mysql` at all...  I would assume he's asking about `sql-server`..

Comment: SQL is a language where you're meant to tell the system "what you want", not "how to do it" - so unless there's an actual performance issue with the query (and if there is, you ought to actually find out where the performance cost is - the system can tell you by generating query plans), just write the most straightforward code that expresses what you need.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you should have added your comment as an answer because that is what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My copy-pasted comment:

Once, as [opposed to COALESCE](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull):

> Used with Subqueries
>
> The ISNULL function has an important advantage over COALESCE in that
>   internally it doesn't evaluate an input expression more than once. In
>   accordance with standard SQL, COALESCE(v1, v2) is simply internally
>   translated to CASE WHEN v1 IS NOT NULL THEN v1 ELSE v2 END. As a
>   result, SQL Server might evaluate the expression v1 more than once,
>   which can lead to all kinds of surprising results.